# Perfect Square Root in PHP

Tags: php

I want my program to determine whether the two integers entered by the user is odd, even and a perfect square.

This is what I have so far for the odd and even:

```
<?php
$number = [$_POST["number_1","number_2" ];

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    if ($i %2==0);{
        echo "$i is even. <br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "$i is odd. <br>";
    }
}
```

So it will display:

> x is odd
>   x is even 
>   etc.

But how do I add a code in such a way that it also determines if it is a perfect square? If it is a perfect square, I want it to display as follows:

> x is even and a perfect square

Comment: What's the purpose of `$number` in that script?

Comment: Your acceptance record is questionable. Questions with solutions should be marked / accepted as solved. It tells everyone / the system that other answers are no longer needed.

Comment: @FirstOne it is linked to an html form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function for that: [**gmp_perfect_square**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-perfect-square.php). For your code:

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    if($i %2 == 0){
        echo "$i is even";
    }else{
        echo "$i is odd";
    }
    echo gmp_perfect_square($i) ? ' and a perfect square.<br>' : '.<br>';
}
```

Output:

> 0 is even and a perfect square.
>   1 is odd and a perfect square.
>   2 is even.
>   3 is odd.
>   4 is even and a perfect square.
>   5 is odd.
>   6 is even.
>   7 is odd.
>   8 is even.
>   9 is odd and a perfect square.

Answer (score 4):

`sqrt()` will return a float, so to check if its a whole number, which makes it a perfect square, you can compare the result of that to a `floor()` of the same.

```
if (sqrt(9) == floor(sqrt(9)))
    echo "9 is a perfect square";
```

A [live demo](https://3v4l.org/7jEJe) shows you that this works.

So for you, that would be

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    if ($i %2==0) {
        echo "$i is even";
    }
    else {
        echo "$i is odd";
    }
    if (sqrt($i) == floor(sqrt($i)))
        echo " and is a perfect square";
    echo ".<br />";
}
```

See this [live demo](https://3v4l.org/eUGba).

Comment: I like your answer better than the accepted one because yours doesn't require extra extension.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to comman for both you can do it using [sqrt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqrt.php) function.

and [is_int()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) will help you to check datatype of variable returned by `sqrt()`

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    $sqrt_status = "";
    if(is_int(sqrt($i))){
      $sqrt_status = "and a perfect square";
    }
    if ($i %2==0);{
        echo "$i is even $sqrt_status <br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "$i is odd $sqrt_status  <br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, because `sqrt()` always returns a float, so `is_int()` will always fail.

Comment: `(int)sqrt($i) == sqrt($i)` could be a solution, personally prefer `floor(sqrt($i)) === sqrt($i)`